# Magnolia Groovy Access Taskmanager

Tags: groovy, magnolia

I'd like to access the taskmanager in Magnolia CMS from within a Groovy script. Reason is to archive old tasks in the system (half automatically).

What I tried is something like this:

```
import info.magnolia.task.*
import info.magnolia.jcr.predicate.NodeTypePredicate;
import info.magnolia.importexport.DataTransporter

repository = "tasks"
nodeType = "mgnl:task"

session = ctx.getJCRSession(repository)
collection = NodeUtil.collectAllChildren(session.getRootNode(), new NodeTypePredicate(nodeType))


collection.each { node->
  println(node)
  println(node.name)
  taskManager.archiveTask(node.name);
  println "node done"
}
```

But taskmanager is of course not known. How can I get access to it using Groovy?

Answer (score 1):

All the components such as managers, registries and others are usually injected and available in Magnolia via guice containers.

Either you can turn your script to class and let guice instantiate it for you or you can use shortcut to get the instance of component you want from guice container like:

`tasksManager = Components.getComponent(TasksManager.class)`